# System.Threading.ThreadStateException OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, adb

Today, I was trying to make an adb client in C# with a decent GUI.
So, i 've done some research and found SharpAdbClient.

To do a file push, I use `var file = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();` to select a file.
But if I try pushing a big file, the GUI stops responding (how it's supposed to be).

So, to solve this issue, I've set up a thread that does the push but I've got a `ThreadStateException` when I try to launch the `OpenFileDialog`.

Here's an example code:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread pushFile = new Thread(push);
    pushFile.Start();
}

private void push()
{
    var device = AdbClient.Instance.GetDevices().First();
    var file = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
    var p = new Progress<int>(Progress_Bar);

    String newPath = textBox2.Text;
    if (file == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        String filePath = openFileDialog2.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog2.FileName;
        using (SyncService service = new SyncService(new AdbSocket(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, AdbClient.AdbServerPort)), device))
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            service.Push(stream, newPath, 444, DateTime.Now, p, CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please send the exception message and stack trace.

Comment: Can't you retrieve the file from `openFileDialog2` before starting the thread, validate, then pass the file path to the thread as its `object` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't invoke UI-methods on threads that are not the GUI thread. You'll have to dispatch that to the correct thread. In WinForms, you'd use `Invoke`, `BeginInvoke` and similar to do that.

Have a look at the [`Control.Invoke` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8) for more information on this.